# Javascript to hide div when excel dialog box is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I have the following javascript code that is triggered when the user clicks on the excel image.

```js
$("#excel").on("click", function () {
  $('#revealSpinningWheel').reveal();
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('#revealSpinningWheel').hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="revealSpinningWheel" class="reveal-modal">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i>
</div>
```

Basically this code is supposed to launch a Loading dialog box with a spinner wheel. The challenge that I am having is that when excel dialog box is loaded, I don't know how to stop displaying the Loading dialog box. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Thanks,
Swamy

Comment: Just try: `$('#revealSpinningWheel').trigger('reveal:close');`

Comment: Wow!! That works. Thank you :)

Comment: This answer is good but it is just showing the Loading dialog box and going away in like 1 sec. The loading dialog box is not waiting for the excel dialog box to show up and then stop displaying. Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
$('#revealSpinningWheel').trigger('reveal:close');
```

This piece of cod should close the reveal modal.